# Which version of Ubuntu is suitable for my Intel Atom N2600 processor?

Tags: software-recommendation, intel

I have a laptop, its configuration is as follows:

```
Processor: Intel Atom N2600 (1.6 Ghz, 1 MB cache)
memory: 1 GB
HDD: 320 GB
```

Which version of Ubuntu is suitable for this PC?

Answer (score 0):

[That processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/58916/) will support both 32bit and 64bit versions of Ubuntu.

Because you have such a small amount of RAM, I'd probably recommend the 32bit version. If you can get more RAM, the 64bit version will run slightly faster.

Comment: you mean ubuntu or Xubuntu. If ubuntu then which version of ubuntu is suitable

Comment: I was talking about Ubuntu. But Kubuntu, Xubuntu and the others are all fine options too. If you find Ubuntu doesn't work well, Xubuntu might be worth a peek. It should work though and the rest is really just personal preference.

Comment: thank u for ur great time.please give me instructions .. how to install ubuntu without damaging existing windows 7.p